# Selecting specific information for a subgroup

Tags: python

I'm still new to coding and am not sure if I'm using the correct terminology. I want to select specific data from a column.

Looked through my homework notes for an example but couldn't.

```
TV = show[show.Group == ['Lost', 'Simpsons', 'Family Guy']]

if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):
    raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Any errors? What is the output?

Comment: This is the error: 

`if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):`

`raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')`

It would help if I got definitions on what this command is. I'm learning through online school.

Comment: Are you able to share what “show” is?

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood right, you are using pandas.
So in order to access the rows with some precise value in some column, you can do the following code:

```
TV = show[show.Group == 'Family Guy']
```

where Group is the column where you are searching the value 'Family Guy'.
So this code return all the rows with values 'Family Guy' in the column 'Group'